# Quantifier elimination, $(\mathbb{R}, <)$

Tags: model-theory, quantifiers, quantifier-elimination

I have a general question about quantifier elimination.
Which kinds of formulas do you have to observe?

For example let T be the theory of $(\mathbb{R}, <)$ and I want to show, that this theory has quantifier elimination.

What do I have to do in general to proof it. 
Are there just specific formulas I have to observe?
Does quantifier elimination always have the same steps, so you always observe the same formulas and show that they are equivalent to a quantifier free formula?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Spelling improved.

Comment: Sorry for the spelling mistake. I am not a native speaker. Could you get more specific about the formulas I have to observe and eliminate the quantifiers.

Comment: It is not that easy. There are some general criteria/method (e.g. back and forth) for QE, but there is no silver bullet, and not a partcular formula to look at.  Sorry for the -1

Comment: So it depends, which form of a formula you have to observe? I thought it is more "step-by-step". First you observe  terms. Than you try to get rid of negation $\neg$ and so on.

Answer (score 2):

In proving quantifier elimination, it suffices to treat formulas consisting of a single existential quantifier applied to a conjunction of atomic and negated atomic formulas.  But that is, as far as I know, the only general reduction available.  After that, you need to consider the particular theory and do some real work.